# How to justify-items of last columns differently than all others?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In excel we can choose if the text is centered, left, or right aligned in a cell based on which column it is in. I am trying to do the same thing using a grid in tailwindcss. Is there a way to specify which columns use "justify-items-center", "justify-items-start", and "justify-items-end"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-center`, `text-left` and `text-right` accordingly to the respective cells to align the text accordingly

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-5 bg-pink-100">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      <div class="text-left bg-pink-400">01</div>
      <div class="text-center bg-pink-300">01</div>
      <div class="text-right bg-pink-600">01</div>


      <div class="text-left bg-pink-400">01</div>
      <div class="text-center bg-pink-300">01</div>
      <div class="text-right bg-pink-600">01</div>


      <div class="text-left bg-pink-400">01</div>
      <div class="text-center bg-pink-300">01</div>
      <div class="text-right bg-pink-600">01</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I am able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [justify-self-...](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-self) classes to specify, which rows differ from the rest of the grid:

```html
    <div class="grid justify-items-center ...">
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- ... -->
      <div class="justify-self-start ...">02</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This method is very convenient because I can make them all centered and then only change one column at a time. Thank you.